# Alerting a user when someone replies to their post

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application that allows users to submit posts and comment on other posts. Is it possible to alert the user when someone comments on their post using connect-flash? How else can I do this? I am using node.js and express and mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 approaches:

1. On your client side make some GET request in some time frame, and ask if that post is commented
2. (preferred) Using web sockets (for eg. [Socket.IO](http://socket.io)), make socket between client and server, then when post is commented, send that information to client.

And for both options, make some alert logic on client side